# IEqualityComparer<T> GetHashCode return same values when items are not equal?

Tags: .net, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer

In the "Notes to Implementers" section in the documentation for the [`GetHashCode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132155.aspx) of the [`IEqualityComparer<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx), it states:

> Implementations are required to ensure that if the Equals method
>   returns true for two objects x and y, then the value returned by the
>   GetHashCode method for x must equal the value returned for y.

It's well known why you want two instances of `T` to return the same hash code in the event that two items are equal; them being different would mean they are not equal, while them being the same means that they are *potentially* equal.

I interpret the quote to be undefined for the return value when two instances are *not* equal (even though their values might suggest so).

Take the following for example.  I have a sequence of `int?` which I want to use for [statistical classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) where each non-null `int?` represents an attribute on a class (think enum values).  In the case where these values are null, you don't want the values to be considered equal, as they would bias the training set towards missing values.  If anything, you would want null values in this case when compared to other null values to return false.

The thing is, in the `GetHashCode` method, when given a null, I'd probably want to return 0 (or some other number, maybe [`Int32.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.minvalue.aspx)).  Now, I know that when anything is keyed using this `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation, the performance for checking for existence of a key in the dictionary is not going to be optimal for those cases.

That said, is it valid to return a value known to conflict for other values when `GetHashCode` is called, when the call to `Equals` returns false?  I'm leaning towards yes, as the quote above is undefined in this matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is *absolutely necessary* for almost *all* types for there to be two values `v1` and `v2` such that

```
v1.Equals(v2) == false
v1.GetHashCode() == v2.GetHashCode()
```

... or the equivalent with an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. The only cases where that *isn't* the case are where there are at most 2<sup>32</sup> distinct (non-equal) values. As soon as there are more values than that, the [pigeon-hole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) *forces* hash codes to be reused - there just aren't enough hash codes to go round!

Eric Lippert had a [*great* blog post on hash codes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) which is well worth a read. Basically I think you've got the right ideas, but it's worth reinforcing them.

The issue of nulls is an interesting one, by the way. `IEqualityComparer<T>` allows `GetHashCode` to throw an exception, but I believe the built-in `Comparer<T>` implementations never do. It sounds like you do have one problem though - that `Equals` should be reflexive - so a null value *should* be equal to itself. You may need to think about that one carefully... can you represent "different" null values?

Comment: From a .NET perspective I agree, `null` is `null` and should be equal; but that's the constraint in the .NET world.  When comparing values in statistics, if a value is not recorded/missing, then I'd translate that into `null` in .NET.  The interesting part comes when you have missing values and how to interpret them; equal [nominal values](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15154/are-nominal-attributes-strict-classifications-and-equivalent-to-enumerations-in-p) are grouped together to help determine classification but missing values are considered not equal to each other.

Comment: @casperOne: It's not just a constraint in the C# world - it's a documented requirement of `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Anyone using `IEqualityComparer<T>` should be able to rely on `Equals(x, x)` returning true. I dare say there are useful reasons to break out of that model, but potentially you shouldn't be trying to squeeze the model into `IEqualityComparer<T>` at that point.

Comment: This prevents skewing classification based on the missing presence of an attribute.  I think we're on the same page, I knew that pigeon-holing would occur at one point, the thing is, is it ok for it to occur when `Equals` is false, and your response leads me to believe that the answer is yes.  However, I'm realizing now that the better approach would be to have a specific method to indicate by the attribute provider indicating whether or not it is "missing", as opposed to using *only* `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: @casperOne: The answer to your initial question is definitely yes... any *clients* of `IEqualityComparer<T>` *must not* assume that two values are considered equal just because they have the same hash code.

Comment: An update, I changed the framework to consider `null` to be missing; a custom definition of "missing" raised too many issues around comparison in general, and it was *much* easier to say "null means 'missing'" (inspired by this post).

Answer (score 2):

IMO: Since `Equals` is always the final arbiter on the equality of objects, `GetHashCode` is only ever a shortcut for non-equal values.  In the case of identical values returned from `GetHashCode` (regardless of whether the objects are *actually* equal), `Equals` will then always be called to compare.  It's expected that `GetHashCode` is likely to conflict between non-equal values.  I don't see anything ambiguous or undefined about this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can return any value you want, as long as the condition you quote is satisfied. Otherwise, classes that depend on this condition will not work correctly.

For example, take a dictionary that is indexed by a case-insensitive key, and say your implementation of GetHashCode returns the value of the first character. So "A" and "a" are equal but have different hash values (65 and 97). In other words: you violate the rule. If you then do something like:

```
dict["A"] = "something";
Console.WriteLine(dict["a"]);
```

then the second line will likely fail with a KeyNotFoundException even though the keys "A" and "a" are equal.